# Get nested relationship where use belongs to page and has the correct roles

Tags: laravel

So, I am trying to check if a user belongs to a page that owns a job.

The relationships are like so:

user.php

```
/**
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
 */
public function pages(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Page::class);
}
```

page.php

```
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
*/
public function users(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
}

/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
*/
public function jobs(): HasMany
{
    return $this->hasMany(Job::class);
}
```

job.php

```
/**
* @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
*/
public function page(): BelongsTo
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Page::class);
}
```

Now, I want to see if a user belongs to a page that owns the job:

```
$job = Job::find(1); //belongs to page_id 1, has job_id 1
$user = User::find(1); // only owns 1 page and 1 job.
```

I can change my `Job::find(1)` to any idea, and the code below will always return true, even if `User::find(1)` doesn't belong to a page that owns that job.

The `$job` variable exists, and is a eloquent model for the Job.

```
return $job->page->whereHas('users', function($query) use($user) {
    $query->where('page_user.user_id', $user->id);
    $query->whereIn('page_user.role', ['admin', 'editor']);
})->exists();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This should help https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through

Comment: i think you should use morph relation in your case

Comment: and you have user belongsTo page and page belongsTo user  you need change to user has many page

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is this part: `$this->page->whereHas(...)`. `$this->page` is an Eloquent Collection and you're treating it like a Query Builder. To append a query you need to call the relationship method, in this case `page()` like in [the example in the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships).

```php
return $job->page()
    ->whereHas('users', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('page_user.user_id', $user->id);
        $query->whereIn('page_user.role', ['admin', 'editor']);
    })
    ->exists();
```